# focusing on a div and blurring area aound the div like modal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div holding a form visible while blurring the area surrounding the area like a modal.

This idea is used in Facebook to focus on the STATUS BOX and blur other areas around the box

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Show us what code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is *not* a coding service. However, this was interesting so I thought I'd play a bit. Traditionally you *should attempt this on your own* and then ask if you have questions, showing your work. In most cases you shouldn't expect others to write code for you if you can't show you are at least attempting to solve the issue yourself.

All that being written.....

You could use `clone()` to copy the wanted focus area and then overlay that on the rest of the original container. Then blur the container. This way the `clone()` would not be altered by the blur.

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {

 var theDiv = $(this).attr('id'); //the ID of the div to focus
 var theText = $(this).text();
 var position = $(this).position(); //gets current position of focus div
  
if ($('.popped').is(':visible')) {

  $('.popped').fadeOut(500); //remove clone if it's visible
    
  } else {
    
    $(this).clone().addClass('popped') //clone the target
   .appendTo("body").css({ //move clone into position
      left: position.left,
      top: position.top 
    })
      .text(theText + ' ::  left: ' + position.left + ', Top: ' + position.top);
      
    }
  
$('#wrap').toggleClass('blurred'); //blur the main container
});
```

```css
body { background: #ddd; }
#wrap { 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 500px;
    transition: all .4s;
}

div { 
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 100%;
}


  .popped {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5000;
    width: 500px; /* same width ans main container (or original div) */
    margin:  15px 18px; /* compensates for blur -- blur distance times 2 */
  }
  
  
  .blurred {
    filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .4s;
  }
  

h3 { text-align: center; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 0.7em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="wrap" class="">
<div id="one">First div</div>
<div id="two">This is number 2</div>
<div id="three">A third Div</div>
<div id="four">4th and final</div>
  <h3>Click a row to focus on it</h3>
</section>
```

This reads the `ID` of the div that was clicked and will clone that div and position the clone in a similar location within the viewport. You could easily alter this to work with a button click or some other event.

This would obviously *need some adjustment* for each situation, but overall this method may work.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `dialog()`, like the following code taken from `jQueryUI` site which you can find [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form):

```js
$(function() {
  var dialog, form,

    // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
    emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
    name = $("#name"),
    email = $("#email"),
    password = $("#password"),
    allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
    tips = $(".validateTips");

  function updateTips(t) {
    tips
      .text(t)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {
      tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
  }

  function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
        min + " and " + max + ".");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips(n);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function addUser() {
    var valid = true;
    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

    valid = valid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
    valid = valid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
    valid = valid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);

    valid = valid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter.");
    valid = valid && checkRegexp(email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
    valid = valid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

    if (valid) {
      $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
      dialog.dialog("close");
    }
    return valid;
  }

  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create an account": addUser,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
      allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
  });

  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
  });

  $("#create-user").button().on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-draggable,
.ui-droppable {
  background-position: top;
}
label,
input {
  display: block;
}
input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: .6em 0;
}
div#users-contain {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
div#users-contain table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
div#users-contain table td,
div#users-contain table th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
  padding: .3em;
}
.validateTips {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

Comment: "...while blurring the area..."

Comment: @showdev I see what you mean thanks for pointing that out. I have just updated my answer. This time the surrounding area gets grayed out when the modal dialog box appears.

Comment: Thanks for updating! Great example. I thought the OP is looking to actually [blur the background](https://codepen.io/chrisyap/pen/HCjzL) content, but I could be mistaken.